# Lint Warning ExportedContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-lint

I have an exported `ContentProvider` that I use for accessing images the user wants to share through other apps. Simply, the user clicks on a share button in my app, I show her a list of apps that can share the image and she picks one of the apps (which calls my `ContentProvider` to get the images based on the Uri).

However, there is a lint warning `ExportedContentProvider` saying I should use a permission. If I do set a permission, how would the other apps know the permission to access the images?

Answer (score -2):

The permission Lint is talking about, is not about "accessing images". It is more about "using your ContentProvider".

When the user will pick an app to share an image, you will give an URI to this app, it will not your ContentProvider. Something like:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Make sur the Uri you're giving to sharing apps represents **the path to the image file**. 
Not the Uri you're using to query your provider.

To avoid the Lint warning, you can just add

```
android:exported="false"
```

in the [provider tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported) of your manifest.

Your provider will then be usable only from your application.

Comment: I know Lint is talking about using my ContentProvider. If I put exported to false then there is no way other apps can access the images from the contentProvider even though they have the uri.

Comment: That's because you're giving the Uri to access the image with the provider. You should give the Uri of the image file instead. The Uri you're giving to the sharing app, must represent a path to a file on SDCard or somthing like that. The Uri should not represent something related to your ContentProvider.

Comment: I disagree with this approach. The recommended way of sharing images is to give an URI and then the app ContentProvider to actually provide the data. Giving a path to a file on the SD card is not ideal (permissions of the file, the location may change, maybe you don't want the files to be accessed directly but only through an app etc.) Popular apps use Content Providers to share their data.